# Получение координат клика ЛКМ в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, координаты, tkinter-canvas

Подскажите, пожалуйста, реализацию получения координат клика левой кнопки мыши. Желательно чтобы работало на *Python 3.7*, но можно и на *Python 3.6*. \

Программа должна работать на *Windows 10*. 
В моей программе клик происходит по `canvas` из библиотеки *tkinter*.

Comment: Операционная система какая?

Comment: Программа должна работать на windows 10. В моей программе клик происходит по canvas из библиотеки tkinter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x600+1+1')

canv = Canvas(bg='white')
canv.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

def click(event):                        # <---
    print(event.x, event.y)

canv.bind('<1>',click)                   # <---

# ...
```